# useContext React not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I am trying to build a simple React App with some CRUD connected to a Rails API.
The structure of the project is this:

```
App.js
 -> UserIndex
   --> Form
   --> User
 -> User
```

I want to send a value (a function) from `<App />` to its grandchild (NOT the immediate child) `<User />`.

This is `<App />`:

```
import "./App.css";
import User from "./components/User";
import UserIndex from "./components/UserIndex";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const UserContext = createContext();

  function handleShow() {
    console.log("showed!");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <UserContext.Provider value={handleShow}>
            <Route path="/" element={<UserIndex />}></Route>
          </UserContext.Provider>
          <Route
            path="users/:userId"
            element={<User id={user.id} name={user.name} email={user.email} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I imported `CreateContext` and created it and also provided it with `UserContext.Provider`.

And this is the `<User />`:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";

function User(props) {
  const userName = useContext(UserContext);
  return (
    <div className="centerText">
      <Link
        href={`/users/${props.id}`}
        color="inherit"
        onClick={props.handleShow}
      >
        <h4>{props.name}</h4>
        <h4>{props.email}</h4>
      </Link>
      {props.deleteData && <button onClick={props.deleteData}>Delete</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

I imported `useContext` and I am trying to get the `UserContext` that I provided but it doesn´t work. It says: `userContext is not defined`.

Tried also wrapping everything on the `UserContext.Provider` like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <UserContext.Provider value={handleShow}>
            <Route path="/" element={<UserIndex />}></Route>

            <Route
              path="users/:userId"
              element={
                <User id={user.id} name={user.name} email={user.email} />
              }
            />
          </UserContext.Provider>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

But it doesnt work either. I searched on the Internet but all the examples are in the same `.js` file so there is no problem fetching the `UserContext`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

After following the corrections this is how it looks now.

```
import "./App.css";
import User from "./components/User";
import UserIndex from "./components/UserIndex";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext();

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  // function handleShow() {
  //   console.log("showed!");
  // }
  const handleShow = "fñalksdjfñdlskfjds";

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <UserContext.Provider value={handleShow}>
                <UserIndex />
              </UserContext.Provider>
            }
          ></Route>

          <Route
            path="users/:userId"
            element={<User id={1} name={"hey"} email={"there"} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "@mui/material";
import axios from "axios";
import UserContext from "../App";

function User(props) {
  console.log(UserContext);
  const userName = useContext(UserContext);

  console.log(userName);

  return (
    <div className="centerText">
      <Link
        href={`/users/${props.id}`}
        color="inherit"
        onClick={props.handleShow}
      >
        <h4>{props.name}</h4>
        <h4>{props.email}</h4>
      </Link>
      {props.deleteData && <button onClick={props.deleteData}>Delete</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare & export UserContext outside App.

```
export const UserContext = createContext();

function App() {
...
```

Then

```
import { UserContext } from '/App';
```

Comment: Thank you! I am getting an error though saying: `[undefined] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>` . If I comment the `<UserContext.Provider value={handleShow}>` in my `App.js` it goes away so I think the `Provider` is conflicting with the `Routes` ? How could I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Provider can be inside `element` for component specific use cases or `parent` of `router`. Routes can only have `route` as a valid child.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more thing that popped up if you dont mind. Now it is working but when I `console.log(userName)` in the `<User />` after consuming the context with `const userName = useContext(UserContext);`, nothing appears. Only `undefined`. I am passing a function so I changed it to a simple `const` like `const handleShow = "fñalksdjfñdlskfjds";` but it still doesnt show anything. Am I doing something wrong? I edited how the project is looking to make it easier to check

Comment: importing with curly braces works fine : { UserContext }

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a new file and name it UserContext.js

2- Create UserContext const inside UserContext.js and export it :

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

const UserContext = createContext();

export  default UserContext;
```

3- import UserContext in the wanted file:

```
import UserContext from "./UserContext";
```

4-get the wanted info like this :

```
const  UserInfo = useContext(UserContext);
```

**Note:** don't forget to import useContext from react